# Tool for Desining text based AI

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I was wondering if there's any open-source tool that I can use to design an AI which would read sentences from a file, understand their structure( by breaking them into their basic components) and then report back its components in detail.

I will provide it some sets of words belonging to different components of sentences(like set of prepositions, set of verbs, set of adjectives, etc) so as to help it determine different components.

I have an elaborate plan for it but **my question is whether there's a tool available or do I have to program it from the scratch**?

Comment: There are many many open source natural language processors out there.

Comment: @KDecker : Can you name some that are well documented?

Comment: No I've never used any. A quick google search will give much more information on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a [Parts of Speech Tagger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging), of which there are many. They are actually not all that hard to write (I made a simple one during grad school) but robust taggers do take a fair amount of work.

[Here](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html) is one that is a part of the popular [NLTK Package](http://www.nltk.org/) for Python.

Just as an aside, there is a lot more to Natural Language understanding that POS, but POS tags could be part of the feature vector that you feed into a larger ML/AI algorithm.